# No notifications for comments at least in iOS app

Tags: bug, ios-app, notifications

I don't see any iOS notifications about comments at least in current version of iOS app. 
All types of notifications are enabled in settings.

- App Version: 1.7.0.1
- Device: Unknown (iPad7,3)
- OS Version: Version 10.3.3 (Build 14G60)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notifications started working after reinstalling the application. Reinstallation was required to reanimate the application after the crash described in [the Ethan Bierlein's question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299352/339911).