# Stack Exchange iOS app crashes when opening questions with large code blocks

Tags: bug, ios-app

Whenever I attempt to open questions in the Stack Exchange iOS app with extremely large sections of formatted code (like [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/172170/ascii-text-based-rpg-game-in-c) on Code Review), the app will crash.

Version information:

- App Version: 1.6.2.5
- Device: iPhone 6s Plus
- OS Version: Version 10.3.2 (Build 14F89)

After I updated the app to 1.6.6, it did not crash immediately upon opening an offending question, but if I scrolled down by any significant amount, the app would still crash.

Comment: Last official version is 1.6.6. Try to update the app first. Can't repro on my TestFlight 1.7.0.1 build .

Comment: @alexolut See my edit.

Comment: Crash for me too in portrait mode. And now I can't recover app ... :(